# Why is $(J : I ) = \{x \in R\mid xI \subset J \}$ an ideal?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $R$ be a commutative ring with $1$. If $I , J \lhd R$ then we define $(J : I ) = \{x \in R\mid xI \subset J \}$.

Please help me to show that $$(J : I )\lhd R$$

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you know the definition of an ideal?  Can you check if the conditions are satisfied?

Comment: yes we first need to prove that 1)$(J:I)$ is non empty, 2)if $x\in (J:I)$ then $-x\in (J:I)$, 3) if $x,y\in (J:I)$ then $x+y\in (J:I)$, 5) if $x\in R$ and $y\in (J:I)$ then $xy\in (J:I)$ but dont manage to prove this can you please help me to do so?

Comment: Maybe an example might help.  What if $R = \mathbb{Z}$, $I = 2\mathbb{Z}$, and $J = 6\mathbb{Z}$.  What is $(J:I)$?

Comment: c'est $3\mathbb{Z}$

Comment: This question probably already is a duplicate, but since I can't find one, the now-useful title should help people find it in the future.

Comment: $0\in (J:I)$ then  $(J:I)$ is non empty, 2) let $x\in (J:I)$ then $xI\subset J$ then $-xI=xI\in J$, 3) let $x,y\in (J:I)$ then $xI\subset (J:I)$ and $yI\subset (J:I)$ then $(x+y)I=xI+yI\subset (J:I)$ hence $(x+y)\in (J:I)$, 4) let $x\in R, y\in (J:I)$ then $yI\subset (J:I)$ then $xyI=yxI\subset (J:I)$ can you please help me to formulate this answer with more details ? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

*Some details for the last property*:

> If $y\in (J:I)$, and  $x\in R$, then $xy\in (J:I)$.

By definition, for all $i\in I$, $y\mkern2mui\in J$, and we must show the same property is satisfied by $xy$. Now
$$(xy)i=x(yi)$$
lies in $J$ because $y\mkern2mui$ lies in $J$ by the hypothesis on $y$, and $J$ is an ideal.

*Edit*:

To prove $\;\operatorname{Hom}(R/I, R/J)\simeq (J:I)/J$, you can prove this more general following assertion: for any $R$-module $M$,
$$\operatorname{Hom}(R/I, M)\simeq(0:_M I)\qquad (\text{the annihilator of $I$ in $M$)}$$
Indeed, a homomorphism from $R/I$ to $M$ corresponds to a homomorphism $\varphi:R\to M$ which vanishes on $I$, and such a $\varphi$ is uniquely determined by the value of $\;\varphi(1)$.

Comment: I am trying to show that $Hom_R(R/I ,R/J )\cong
(J : I )/J$ via the map $φ \mapsto  φ(1+I ).$ using the first isomorphism theorem can you please help me to do so? thanks

Comment: @mora: I've sketched  what has to be proved. Please  see if my edit helps.

Comment: we didn't study yet ''the annihilator'', can you please instead help me to prove that the map $\psi:Hom(R/I,R/J)\to (J:I)/J$ , $\phi\mapsto \phi(1+I)$  is well defined and is bijective?

Comment: There's no particular theory about the annihilator: it's defined the same way as $(J:I)$: the set of elements$m\in M$ such that $im=0$ for all $i\in I$. In your case, the module $M$ will clearly be $R/J$.

Comment: I see that $M=R/J$ and $(0:_MI)=J:I)/J$ but what i don't manage to prove is that the map  is well defined and is bijective (:

Comment: Please see my answer to your following post.